Azure container group container IP address
I just started to learn on how to work with Azure Containers so trying to deploy a simple container as part of Azure Container Group. Very simple configuration and container actually does start-up and running. The main issue is that it could not connect to anything in internet  :(
While checking the IP addresses I see that Container Group assigned IP: 1.2.3.4  but inside ubuntu based container I see this configuration:
> route -n

Kernel IP routing table
Destination   Gateway   Genmask          Flags  Metrics  Ref   Use  iface
0.0.0.0       1.2.3.18  0.0.0.0          UG     1        0     0    eth0
1.2.3.55      0.0.0.0   255.255.255.128  U      0        0     0    eth0
169.254.128.0 0.0.0.0   255.255.128.9    U      0        0     0    eth0

> ifconfig

eth0: flags=4163<UP, ......................
       inet 1.2.3.4  netmask 255.255.255.128  broadcast  1.2.3.255
       .......

somehow eth0 is configured with IP address of Container Group IP but routing table seems to be wrong. I am not sure where those IP addresses in routing table come from and why are so different (random-choosen ?) from Container Group address
What I am missing ? Is it something in configuration of ARM Template ? What I can do about this routing table ?
Update: Everything was setup correctly but currently we have a an internal issue with gateway so no traffic could pass through

The container's routing table is misconfigured, causing it to be unable to reach the internet.
The default gateway (0.0.0.0) should typically be set to the gateway address provided by the virtual network or Azure Container Instance. The IP 1.2.3.18 might not be correct.
Delete the incorrect default gateway
sudo route del default gw 1.2.3.18
Add the correct default gateway
sudo route add default gw <correct_gateway_ip> eth0

yes.. the routing table is incorrect.. but why did it happen in the first place ? Why this container was configured with this gateway address ? I didn't enter any gateway address anywhere in ARM Template or any other place that I can remember

Even if you do not specify any gateway address in the ARM Template, a gateway address will be assigned by default. I followed this Microsoft documentation for creating the container group.

sorry - there's no way that I could defined a gateway address in container. I can not even reach it. The only option that I have in ARM template is to assign IP address to Container Group: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.containerinstance/containergroups?pivots=deployment-language-arm-template#ipaddress-1      you even bring the same documentation but from another section. I still don't know why the container set the default  gateway to such strange address. It is even does not exist - nothing assigned to this address

To access the internet from container instances, you need to add DNS configuration in the container group configuration.
